# Mustache functions possible in CartoDB tooltip templates?

Tags: carto, carto-js

CartoDB.js uses the [mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) library to render tooltip windows. One of the features of mustache.js is allows functions to be defined, which are called when the template is rendered. An example is given below:

```
{
  "beatles": [
    { "firstName": "John", "lastName": "Lennon" },
    { "firstName": "Paul", "lastName": "McCartney" },
    { "firstName": "George", "lastName": "Harrison" },
    { "firstName": "Ringo", "lastName": "Starr" }
  ],
  "name": function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
```

Is it possible to pass such a function to a CartoDB tooltip template? I understand how basic variable substitution works, I am talking about the case where a function is called to generate the substitution. In the above example that is:

```
 "name": function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
```

which would be referenced as `{{name}}` in the template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep! Checkout the documentation in CartoDB.js for more on how to integrate it into your map application: https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/ui-functions/

If you checkout the infowindow or tooltip template code, which you can access through the tray on the right in the CartoDB Editor -> Infowindow tab. Read more in the [Editor docs](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor/maps/#infowindows) to see how to change the HTML template for your infowindows/tooltips.

By the way, a template looks something like this:

```
<div class="cartodb-tooltip-content-wrapper">
  <div class="cartodb-tooltip-content">
    <h4>Area (Sq. Miles)</h4>
    <p>{{area_sq_miles}}</p>
    <h4>rank</h4>
    <p>{{rank}}</p>
    <h4>District Number</h4>
    <p>{{cd114fp}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

The template reads from the data available via the SQL applied in the SQL tab. In the example above, the fields `area_sq_miles`, `rank`, and `cd114fp` are all available column names in the dataset associated with the layer that the tooltip is associated with.

[Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) is a dependency of CartoDB.js, so you can use it when writing JavaScript applications without including the script elsewhere. A common use of it is using CartoDB's [`sql.execute`](https://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/cartodb-js/sql/#sqlexecutesql-vars-options-callback) to get JSON response and then using the templating of [`Mustache.render`](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/#usage).

Also, checkout the CartoDB tutorial on custom interactivity where Mustache templates are discussed: https://docs.cartodb.com/tutorials/custom_interactivity/

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't as clear as I could have been. I was talking about the case where instead of directly substituting the column value from the SQL row, a function is applied to format that value. Using your example, imagine a `{{area_sq_km}}` which didn't map to column name, but instead applied a javascript function, e.g. with the signature `function(data.content.area_sq_miles)` which computed the value from other fields.

Comment: Behind the scenes CartoDB.js is using mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/), so it can be used as is just as you see in the examples on their github :) Updated answer above to include that.